# how can 32bit program can run in 64bit system

Tags: pointers, 32bit-64bit

how can 32bit program can run in 64bit system?

Because 64bit system will have 64bit memory address.
But 32bit program will try to use 32bit size of memory address.

Ex) C lang: pointer is 4byte, so how can it store 64bit(8byte)of memory address?(if it's running in 64bit system)

Comment: Because it's not running in a 64-bit system. It's running in a 32-bit subsystem that's running in a 64-bit system. Pointers are still 4 bytes (32-bits), and you still have the 32-bit CPU registers; there's no access to 64-bit pointers or registers from that 32-bit app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 64-bit instruction set architectures generally have backwards compatibility features that allow running "legacy" 32-bit code and switching between modes.

Intel processors, for example, start in Real Mode, then the OS jumps into Protected Mode (basically 32-bit,) then the OS jumps into Long Mode (basically 64-bit.) Long mode has another mode inside of it that is used for legacy code, and the instruction encoding is compatible with previous versions of Intel processors.

Side-note: *64-bit* refers to a 64-bit machine word, NOT 64-bit addressing (though often both come together.) That means the basic integer size of a 64-bit processor is 64 bits long, and nothing else. In case of Intel, 64-bit instructions often encode a static address, i.e. the address to a function, as a 32-bit *offset* rather than a 64-bit *pointer*. So, a lot of generated code, in the default code model, will not even encode 64-bit absolute addresses where we before used 32-bit absolute addresses. However, on the other hand, this property is highly desirable, because using relative addresses makes it easier to move code around in memory, and does not sacrifice the ability to make use of 64-bit pointers or addressing.